# Interface Builder: Change control-drag IBOutlet keyboard shortcut

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

Is it possible to change the Control-drag IBOutlet creation keyboard shortcut in Xcode to Shift-drag instead?  I am using one keybaord and mouse between two computer with Sharemouse and Xcode doesn't recognize the Control key properly.

Comment: I think that's unlikely.

Comment: It might be worth trying to contact the developers of ShareMouse to see if they have a workaround, or try one of the other mouse-sharing apps like [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org) or [Teleport](http://abyssoft.com/software/teleport/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the key used for dragging, but you can just do a right-click drag (*i.e.* drag with the right mouse button held down instead of left) rather than control-drag.

You can also do a standard drag from the connections inspector of the utilities panel:
[image: dragging from the utilities panel]